# Is there a formula for TARDIS numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

This is simply a recreational question about some numbers I came up with.

> **Definition:** Let $x\in \Bbb N$ have decimal expansion $x=\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n}$. Call $x$ a *TARDIS number* if $$a_1+a_n<a_2+\dots+a_{n-1}.$$

I call them TARDIS numbers because they're bigger on the inside than on the outside.  Incidentally, the fictional telephone number of the TARDIS is [95475949](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/95475949_(telephone_number)#:%7E:text=95475949%20(telephone%20number)%20%7C%20Tardis%20%7C%20Fandom), a TARDIS number!

They're [new to the OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=120%2C+130%2C+131%2C&language=english&go=Search).

I believe the first few are

$$120, 130, 131, 140, 141, 142,\dots$$

### The Question:

> What is the formula for the $m$th term in the sequence of TARDIS numbers?

### Thoughts:

I don't know.

Writing code that computes the TARDIS numbers less than or equal to, say, $10^k-1$, shouldn't be too difficult; here is what I have in mind (for $k=4$):

```
for r in [1..9] do
   for s in [0..9] do
      for t in [0..9] do
         if t+r<s then
            Print(t+(10*s)+(100*r), "\n");
         fi;
      od;
   od;
od;
```

My guess is that one can't get anything simpler than the definition.

Please help :)

Comment: The code is not general enough! :)   Want help writing it in SymPy or even pure Python?

Comment: I think it will be hard to find a formula for these numbers, since (unless I've made a simple mistake) the fraction of TARDIS numbers $\leq N$ approaches $1$ as $N \to \infty$. After all, the two outermost digits of $x$ cannot sum to more than $18$, so as soon as $x$ has $>20$ digits there are $>18$ inside digits, which will almost always sum to larger than $18$.

Comment: I don't know how to code in those, @DanielDonnelly, so sure, yes, please! :)

Comment: I see, @HallaSurvivor. That's a shame.

Comment: What are these used for?

Comment: Spacetime travel, @DanielDonnelly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, but just instructions on how to generate  the first few examples in Python.

#### Generating examples in Python

1. Download & install [Wingware 101](https://wingware.com/downloads/wingide-101) for your machine.
2. Download & install the [latest Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

   - If there are custom options in the installer, make sure you check at least "Add to Path".  That allows you to access Python interpreter from command line and for Wing IDE to find it automatically.
   - Custom install location is best set to C:\Python311 for example for Python 3.11.
3. Open up Wingware, and go to Project > New Project > Defaults I think.  Save your project inside a folder named TARDIS_numbers on your Desktop.  Call the project TARDIS_numbers as well.
4. If Projects panel is not displayed, open it with Tools menu > Projects.
5. Right-click the blank area in the Project panel and select "Create New File".  Call it either main.py or TARDIS_numbers.py.
6. Copy / paste in the following Python code:

```
from math import log10

N = 10000

def nth_digit(x, n):
    return (x // 10**n) % 10

def num_digits(x):
    return int(log10(x)) + 1

sequence = []    # TARDIS number sequence

for x in range(120, N):
   digits = num_digits(x)
   fst_digit = digit(x, digits - 1)
   lst_digit = digit(x, 0)
   lhs = fst_digit + lst_digit
   rhs = 0

   for d in range(1, digits - 1):   # literally 1...digits - 2 inclusive
      rhs += digit(x, d)

   if lhs < rhs:
      sequence.append(x)

print(sequence)
```

8. Debug the formula since I just coded it in the MSE editor and haven't tested it.
9. Optimize the formula with a smarter strategy (the above is just the naive / brute-force method), if you'd like to.
10. Ping me in chat if something goes wrong or you'd like some help!

Comment: Thank you.  I can definitely learn from this.

Comment: @Shaun yes, I do these mall Python snippets all the time for working with integer sequences.  Remember, Python is good for prototyping and productivity, but C/C++ is 100-1000x faster for scientific computations such as these.  So if say you can only compute up to N = 100 after a few hours for some problem, you'll want to, in addition to optimizing your strategy, code it in C/C++.

Comment: @Shaun once you've found a formula, you can code the formula up in the same file as above, and then compare the two sequences for verifcation purposes.